# Put all headers from current request to other in Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I would like to put all headers of the current httpRequest, to a new other one.

I am implementing this logic, in a Helper class.

I get the current request in this way:

```
private static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

    return ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
}
```

Getting httpHeaders of the current request in this way doesn't work :

```
private static HttpHeaders getCurrentRequestHeaders() {
    HttpServletRequest currentRequest = getCurrentRequest();
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = currentRequest.getHeaderNames();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        httpHeaders.add(headerName, currentRequest.getHeader(headerName));
    }
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

I get the following exception:

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)):
>   only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens

The weird thing, is that the request is performed successfully! so when parsing the response it throws the exception above; But, when not putting all headers(in the request), but only the Cookie header, everything works well.

Comment: please post the *full* exception, what illegal character?

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look